# strtolower <title>

Tags: title

Currently the WordPress Twenty something themes all have this as the  title:

```
<title><?php
    global $page, $paged;
    wp_title('~', true, 'right');
    bloginfo('name');
    $site_description = get_bloginfo('description', 'display');
    if ($site_description && (is_home() || is_front_page()))
        echo " ~ $site_description";
    if ($paged >= 2 || $page >= 2)
        echo ' ~ ' . sprintf(__('Page %s', 'schema'), max($paged, $page));
?></title>
```

Would it be possible to have the whole bit returning as lowercase perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping everything in strtolower should work:

```
<title><?php
global $page, $paged;

echo strtolower(wp_title( '|', false, 'right' ));

echo strtolower(get_bloginfo( 'name' ));

$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
echo strtolower(" | $site_description");

if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
echo strtolower(' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page ) ));

?></title>
```